# Octave: compare two vectors

Tags: octave

I have this vector:

```
t = 1: 10 % t = 1 2 3 ..10

A= [3 4 5] % a column vector
```

If I type:

```
(3 == t)
```

I get the result:

```
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 % it means: 1 at location equals, and 0 at others
```

I want to do this for vector a, meaning that it will take each element in vector A and compare and return another vector. So in this case, the result will be a 3×10 matrix.

But this line will result in an error: `A==t`.

Of course, I can do this by using a for loop, but I want to vectorize this operation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

what you are looking for is the function `ismember`

```
octave> t = 1:10
t =
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10

octave> A = ismember (t, [2 3 4])
A =
   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using octave's broadcasting ability, which exists in 3.6.3 (not sure when it was introduced), you can simply say this:

```
A'==t
```

If you want it to produce the same result as carandraug's `ismember` command, you simply need to add an "any", like this:

```
any(A'==t)
```

This method is much faster than the ismember approach for smaller vectors.

```
octave:209> tic; for i=1:10000 B=ismember(t,A); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 1.5 seconds.
octave:211> tic; for i=1:10000 B=any(A'==t); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.2 seconds.
```

Note: if your version of octave doesn't support broadcasting, or you want to keep it compatible with older versions, A'==t can be replaced by bsxfun(@eq,A',t).

Comment: -1: [Octave broadcasting](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html#Broadcasting) is simply the implicit equivalent of [`bsxfun`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/bsxfun.html). The result is definitely not the same as `ismember`, so it's meaningless to compare between the two.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you'd bothered to read it, you'd see that it's any(A'==t) that is producing the same result as bsxfun. You can try it, if you'd like. As for bsxfun, nobody other than you mentioned anything about bsxfun, so I really don't see the relevance of that point... but even if there was a relevance, code readability is relevant, and if octave with broadcasting is easier to read, it's better. Also, for whatever reason, I've found that broadcasting is slightly faster... looping 10000 times over B=bsxfun(@eq,t,A') requires about 10% more time than looping 10000 times over B=A'==t.

Comment: Can you give an example of ismember giving a different result? Because I can't see any situation in which it would do so. If it does give a different result, is it ismember or my solution that gives the right result?

Comment: I apologize, I indeed missed the `any` when I tried to run your code, so I removed the downvote. However, I do have to point out that `ismember` is noticeably faster for large arrays (thousands of elements).

Comment: Point taken regarding large arrays. I restricted my attention to examples similar to the one given. I've edited the answer slightly to note that it being faster is only true for smaller A arrays.

Comment: This can actually proves useful in some cases. +1. I would also make a note that your solution is equivalent to `any(bsxfun(@eq, A', t))`.